# How to generate sequences of CID ( RFC4122-compliant UUID) in R

Tags: r, simulation

for a clickstream simulation I need to generate a sequence of N client ids, these are defined by Google to be RFC4122 UUID.

These GUID typically look like: "baef6775-eb3a-4ac9-85d3-70e4aa0d9d94"

I found a javascript implementation by
[Philippe Sawicki](http://codingrepo.com/regular-expression/2015/11/23/javascript-generate-uuidguid-for-rfc-4122-version-4-compliant-with-regular-expression/) but I cannot understand it or port it to R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [UUID Package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=uuid) package which does the job:

```
library(uuid)
cid <- UUIDgenerate()

#if ts_list holds timestamps 
cid_list<-sapply(ts_list, UUIDgenerate) #ge cid from time stamps.
```